# Does TransactionScope support atomic DB execution?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope

I am at the moment developping a project where the DAL is implemented in .Net using the ADO Entity Framework.

The DB structure is not straightforward and I would like to be able to ensure that some DB operations are atomic.

I know that you can do that by creating a `STORED PROCEDURE` and using a DB `TRANSACTION` (as mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259803/t-sql-stored-procedure-execution-atomic)). (I'm using SQL Server)

The thing is, I would like to keep the logic on the software side as much as possible, and I was considering using .Net `TransactionScope`. Although I understand that it works well from a software point of view (nothing is committed to the DB until the whole scope is committed), I doubt it still ensures DB atomic execution.

Does somebody know about this?

More specifically, usually the code would look like this:

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
  /*
   * Do some opreations such as reads, write, insert, deletes
   */
   scope.Commit()
}
```

What I'd like to make sure, is that everything within the brackets is done "atomically" (isolation=SERIALIZABLE I guess). What I mean by that is that I don't want the state of the DB to be able to change when the code within the scope is executing.

Comment: The "atomic" unit in an ACID relation database is a transaction. Choose the correct [isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) for the task and commit/rollback appropriately -- this won't help with critical regions outside the data, though (it is strictly related to the RDBMS transactions!). Using a `TransactionScope` is one way to help with such transactions through an implicit thread-local transaction (saves having to pass it about explicitly).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884863/under-what-circumstances-is-an-sqlconnection-automatically-enlisted-in-an-ambient/2886326

Comment: @Mitch: thanks. Do you think the same is true for anything done with the ADO Entities Framework.

Comment: @SRKX
: without checking, I'm not 100% sure. The Entity Framework may alter the default isolation level depending on what's being performed.

Comment: I just updated my answer with Entity Framework details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransactionScope runs the updates in a transaction (and possibly the reads as well depending on your transaction isolation level)

The database providers are already part of this transaction as they are used within the transaction scope - therefore the transaction scope is, effectively, a database transaction (and possibly more if you have multiple databases / message queues / etc involved in the transaction)

**EDIT: Entity Framework Details**

Entity framework uses the underlying provider's connection BeginTransaction method. In the case of SqlConnection it uses the default for SqlServer and so will use ReadCommitted

So if you don't use a transaction scope it will default to Read Committed rather than Serializable

Comment: Ok so in your opinion what should be in the `TransactionScope`? do you think the instance of the model should be created within the scope or only the `SaveChanges()` method is important?

Comment: Create the Model (I assume you mean the ObjectContext wrapper) inside the TransactionScope

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "DB atomic execution"?  There are various transaction isolation levels.

When talking to SQL Server a .NET `TransactionScope` enlists a SQL Server transaction, which by default will be a `Serializable` isolation level.

Comment: TransactionScope uses Serializable by default

Comment: You're right that SQL Server uses READ COMMITTED by default for its transactions - not sure why they chose something different for TxScope - maybe for least surprise for people who weren't used to transactions

Comment: I learnt something today! TransactionScope  does not work as you would expect!

Comment: So basically, by default, everything that happened from the creation of the `TransactionScope` until the `Commit()` call will be treated a a single operation by the DB? including (possibly) table reading, data-processing and so on?

Comment: @SRKK: yes, as long as the connection is enlisted in the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

A Transaction is **always** atomic, whether started in SQL, on in the client (eg TransactionScope)